# Server-side CouchDB AJAX call

Tags: ajax, couchdb

Well, I'm using Mustache templating inside CouchDB shows. Works perfectly. Now I would like to pupulate template with data returned by AJAX. How could I call ajax from inside CouchDB show function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately views, shows, and lists expose no ajax functionality. The best you can do is if your template is returning html to a browser, have the ajax call from the browser.

Comment: I can't use any 3rd party lib using require(XXX) to add that functionality?